# Structured streaming truncates kafka timestamps to seconds

Tags: apache-spark, spark-structured-streaming

I am reading data from Kafka with Spark Structured Streaming and want to include the Kafka timestamp in the message:

```scala
sparkSession.readStream
  .format("kafka")
  .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", "kafka-broker:10000")
  .option("subscribe", "topicname")
  .option("includeTimestamp", true)
  .load()
  .selectExpr("CAST(topic AS STRING)", "CAST(key AS STRING)", "CAST(value AS STRING)", "timestamp")
  .as[(String, String, String, Long)]
```

When I then look at the timestamp it is truncated from milliseconds to seconds. Is there any way I can get the millisecond precision back after reading?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The truncation happens when the timestamps is read as a Long value. This happens in the last line of:

```scala
sparkSession.readStream
  .format("kafka")
  .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", "kafka-broker:10000")
  .option("subscribe", "topicname")
  .option("includeTimestamp", true)
  .load()
  .selectExpr("CAST(topic AS STRING)", "CAST(key AS STRING)", "CAST(value AS STRING)", "timestamp")
  .as[(String, String, String, Long)]
```

It does not truncate when you change the last line to:

```
.as[(String, String, String, Timestamp)]
```

Answer (score 0):

I just tried this quickly in IntelliJ with my local Kafka set-up.

If you are referring to the three dots in the end of the timestamp field as truncation (as in the output below):

```
Batch: 1
-------------------------------------------
+-----+----+--------+--------------------+
|topic| key|   value|           timestamp|
+-----+----+--------+--------------------+
| test|null|test-123|2018-10-07 03:10:...|
| test|null|test-234|2018-10-07 03:10:...|
+-----+----+--------+--------------------+
```

Then you just need to add the following line:

`.option("truncate", false)`

in your `writeStream()` portion like:

```java
Dataset<Row> df = sparkSession
                .readStream()
                .format("kafka")
                .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", "localhost:9092")
                .option("subscribe", "test")
                .option("includeTimestamp", "true")
                .load()
                .selectExpr("CAST(topic AS STRING)", "CAST(key AS STRING)", "CAST(value AS STRING)", "CAST(timestamp as STRING)");

try {
    df.writeStream()
          .outputMode("append")
          .format("console")
          .option("truncate", false)
          .start()
          .awaitTermination();
} catch (StreamingQueryException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

This change gave me the full timestamp in the output:

```
Batch: 1
-------------------------------------------
+-----+----+--------+-----------------------+
|topic|key |value   |timestamp              |
+-----+----+--------+-----------------------+
|test |null|test-123|2018-10-07 03:19:50.677|
|test |null|test-234|2018-10-07 03:19:52.673|
+-----+----+--------+-----------------------+
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: Your approach works. The reason however is that you do CAST(timestamp as STRING). I read the timestamp as a Long which led to the truncation apparently.

Comment: @GiselleVanDongen - Ohk. I didn't try with Long or Timestamp. I just used the ".option("truncate", fasle) method. Anyway, thanks for your answer Upvote :).